# Reducing the computational burden in evaluating a series of formula with Sympy

Tags: c++, optimization, sympy

First, I am not completely sure this is the right stackexchange community. I have also posted on the Math forum, I assume it should be ok as the people looking at the question should have different point of views on overflow vs. math, but just tell me if this is bad and I will remove one of the posts:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2330004/reducing-the-computational-burden-in-evaluating-a-series-of-formula

I have a series of formula (many of them, typically 100) that I obtain from computations with a CAS (Python Sympy). Those formula will be translated into C++, and they should be evaluated efficiently on a micro controller. Many of the computations to perform to evaluate each formula are redundant between different formula. Is there a way to find, with an algorithm in Sympy, an 'optimal', or at least 'reasonable', way to group the computations so as to reduce the number of operations to perform, and to do it in a systematic way? Or should I let the compiler do so (but there are many formula...)?

For example, if many formula include the term

$ \cos\left(\frac{dt}{2} \sqrt{w_x^2 + w_y^2 + w_z^2}\right) $

, I should calculate it first and store it in a variable, let us say $cn$, and use $cn$ for later evaluations. Of course, I can go through the code and do this euristicaly 'by hand' but it is not really scalable, definitely 'ugly' and probably non optimal. I guess, in theory, a 'perfect' C++ compilator should be able to do this task, but I guess if the equations are many and complex enough it will fail to come close to an optimum.

*Edit*: I am of course aware of simple simplifications using sympy, for example http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/simplify/simplify.html#module-sympy.simplify.cse_main or factorize, simplify etc. The difficulty here is, I want to 'cross' the simplifications between several equations.

Comment: It looks like you have wrong assumptions that C++ compilers just can magically optimize things for you because it is a low-level language or something.

Comment: @VTT: I do not think so. I am aware that C++ compilers can optimize code in some measure [inling functions, recognizing repeating pieces of code / formula, doing computations once and using several times as I want here etc], this is why I say a 'perfect' compiler should be able to do this. But I am aware that compilers are not perfect, and therefore I want to do the optimization in Sympy. So the fact that I want to optimize in Sympy is actually because I do not think compilers can do magics ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cse` is able to accept a list of expressions and give the common sub-expressions that appear across all of them.

```
>>> cse([x**2+1, exp(x**2+1), 1/(x**2 + 1)])
([(x0,x2+1)],[x0,exp(x0),1/x0])
```

Comment: That's really nice. My bad, I had used cse before with single expression and should have read again through the doc in a bit more details.